# MySQL / MariaDB granular row size

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Is it possible in MySQL / MariaDB to calculate row size like in PostgreSQL ?
I'm looking to calculate in a multi tenant application how much space did the user use for the database but I couldn't find anything relevant about this.

Comment: show table status; ?

Comment: Do you want "row size"?  Or "table size"?  Or maybe the entire database, if each tenant has his own database?

Comment: Yes Rick, row size then I will need  the entire database and table size. :D been looking into this for a week by now. :D

Answer (score 1):

In phpmyadmin you see the size of every table at the end . after you select a database.

if you want to do this in a query do, you need only the put in your own database name instead of testdb

```
SELECT SUM(Table_Size_MB) 'database_size_MB'
    FROM
        (SELECT table_name AS "Table",
        ROUND(((data_length + index_length + DATA_FREE) / 1024 / 1024), 2) AS "Table_Size_MB"
        FROM information_schema.TABLES
        WHERE table_schema = "testdb"
        ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC) tablessizes;
```

Comment: [data_length](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html) only includes the clusterd index so this excludes blob sizes and text that aren't stored in the table row (after a size of a few K - exact number is an exercise for the reader).

Comment: @danblack - I believe that is not true.  data_length includes the clustered index (`PRIMARY KEY`) and _all_ the data for the rows.  However, the _BTree_ containing the PK excludes the "off-record" big blobs/texts/varchars.

Comment: `data_free` needs to be added to get the disk space consumed.

Comment: ok i added the information for DATA_FREE to the mix.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames good distinction. I'll look carefully before stating something similar again.